# JQuery accordion, position footer according to height

Tags: jquery, height, accordion

I have a made a responsive website which checks the highest column and positions the footer accordingly as I have had to use absolute positioning.  My issue is, I have an accordion on one page and the footer overlaps the content of the accordion.  How can I adjust the below code to take into consideration the highest section of the accordion, or have a new event that registers the setFooter function when the accordian is clicked and the height resized?

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

```
function setFooter() {
        var rightcol = $('._right').height();
        var midcol = $('.col_centre').height();
        //var accordian = '?';

        if (rightcol > midcol) {
            $('.col_centre').css('height', rightcol + 'px');
        }
       /* if (accordian > midcol) {
            $('.col_centre').css('height', checkout + 'px');
        }*/
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    setFooter();

});
$(window).resize(function() {
    setFooter();
});
```

Comment: A quick jsfiddle could make us help you faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code computes the tallest element in "content-div", then use the result value to set your footer top value:

```
var h, elems, max_height;
elems = $( 'content-div' );
for( i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ) {
    h = elems[i].offsetTop + elems[i].offsetHeight + elems[i].style.marginTop + elems[i].style.marginBottom;
    max_height = ( max_height > h ) ? max_height : h;
}
```

e.g.

```
$('#footer').css('top', max_height + 'px');
```